# Parameters of httplib2.Http.request()

Tags: python, parameters, ssl-certificate, httplib2

I was wondering what parameters does the request method of the httplib2.Http class take. I'm trying to use a simple get method but it seems like the url I use provides a certificate that needs verification since I get an SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE error. That's why I was wondering if with the httplib2 library we could tell our request to ignore the certificate verification (like the *unverifiable* parameter of urllib.request).
Here's my code :

```
   import httplib2
   h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
   h.credentials_add(username, password)
   resp, content = h.request(url, "GET")
```

Comment: For help on available parameters, you just need to [read the documentation](http://httplib2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/html/libhttplib2.html#http-objects). Using `ctrl-f` on it will also answer your second question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `disable_ssl_certificate_validation` to ignore certificate verification. Please check the sample below. However, it won't work with **Python 3.x** due to the following bug. So you need to update `Python33\Lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py` as recommended in comments for this issue.

[HTTPS request doesn't work when disable_ssl_certificate_validation = True](https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/issues/detail?id=173)

```
import httplib2

h = httplib2.Http(".cache", disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
resp, content = h.request("https://github.com/", "GET")
```

Patch for Python 3.x:

```
diff --git a/__init__.py b/__init__.py
index 65f90ac..4495994 100644
--- a/__init__.py
+++ b/__init__.py
@@ -823,10 +823,13 @@ class HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout(http.client.HTTPSConnection):
                 context.load_cert_chain(cert_file, key_file)
             if ca_certs:
                 context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
+        check_hostname = True
+        if disable_ssl_certificate_validation:
+            check_hostname = False
         http.client.HTTPSConnection.__init__(
                 self, host, port=port, key_file=key_file,
                 cert_file=cert_file, timeout=timeout, context=context,
-                check_hostname=True)
+                check_hostname=check_hostname)


 SCHEME_TO_CONNECTION = {
```

Comment: Seems fixed in python 3.10